# Tablesorter 2.0: Sorting column having ICD9 codes

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, tablesorter

I have a column in a table that contains ICD9 codes. So it can have values like `4379`, `5186`,`45933,`V420`or`E9539`.

For this sorting does not work. It considers a column as a digit type and applies sort. 
Current output is :

```
4379
5186
45933
V420
E9539
```

I want this column to be sorted in text manner.

It's output should be

```
4379
45933
5186
E9539
V420
```

AS you can see I want order to be based on first character, then second character and so on.

How can I achieve this type of sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure which version of tablesorter you're using, so I'll answer for both.

The original tablesorter (tablesorter.com) v2.0.5 isn't showing either of those outputs, but since you want to apply a basic text sort, not a numeric sort, set the `headers` option to force it to sort text ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eY8uH/1386/)):

```
$('table').tablesorter({
    headers: {
        0: { sorter: 'text' }
    }
});
```

If you are using my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) (currently v2.23.3), then the basic alphanumeric sort does produce the output above. To switch to using a basic text sort, set the [`textSorter` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#textsorter) to use the basic text sort ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/856bzzeL/647/)):

```
$(function () {
    $('table').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        textSorter: {
            // use sortText on the first column only
            0 : $.tablesorter.sortText
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for your response. This does not worked for me. I am using TableSorter 2.17.8

Comment: It has basic sort implemented as ```// basic alphabetical sort
   ts.sortText = function(a, b) {
    return a > b ? 1 : (a < b ? -1 : 0);
   };
``` For this function is it not that 45933 is greater than 5186?

Comment: Thanks. Your second approach was correct. I just had to change sortText line from ```$.tablesorter.sortText``` to ```$.tablesorter.sortText(a,b)```. Can you please update your answer?

Comment: You shouldn't need to include the `(a,b)` because the option value is the function. Look at the demo, it works without it.

Comment: I know right. I don't have to include it but if I don't do that then it does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

The other thing to add is that ICD-9 codes are always listed in the order: numeric, V codes, than E codes. You may wish to reconsider sorting with E codes before V codes, but this would complicate your code as it would no longer be a simple alphanumeric ordering.

Comment: I know. But requirement was for alphanumeric ordering so we are okay here